# how to make this grouped list with this animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

How to make this grouped List view with the grouped date animation. I have already familiar and tried with the grouped list view but that was for header and adjusting vertically header, I want grouped header should be horizontally adjusted with the items as it's in the video and it should scroll double as it's in the video.

[image: Here is the gif of the desired output]

Answer (score 0):

Try [sticky_infinite_list](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_infinite_list):

```
import 'package:sticky_infinite_list/sticky_infinite_list.dart';

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InfiniteList(
      builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        /// Builder requires [InfiniteList] to be returned
        return InfiniteListItem(
          /// Header builder
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              ///...
            );
          },
          /// Content builder
          contentBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              ///...
            );
          },
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but in this package the header is for each item , in my case it will dynamic  . as you can see there can be random sub-childs  of a date as i mention in image . but this dependency don't have that configuration.